# How to find the number of people one should question before....

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A polling agency would like to investigate the relationship between people having seen the movie Jurassic World and people having nightmares. 
In A, 37% of the population has seen the movie.
We also know that in general, 19% of the people that have seen the movie
have nightmares afterwards. How much people in A should the polling agency
expect to question before coming across the first person that has seen the movie and that has had nightmares afterwards ?

I really suck at probability. Here is what I did

```
P(in A)= 0,37
P(movie and nightmare)= 0,19
P(in A movie and nightmare)= 0,19 * 0,37 =0,0703
```

I don't know how to answer how many people one should expect to question before......

I don't even see where to begin :( :(

Can someone help me please???

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric distribution?

Comment: not really. I will check it out

Comment: To say that $\Pr(\text{movie and nightmare}) = 0.19$ is incorrect. Rather, you have $\Pr(\text{nightmare} \mid \text{movie})  = 0.19.$ That is an altogether different statement.

Answer (score 3):

You simply take its inverse to figure out how many people you can expect.

That is, you can expect that it will take $\frac{1}{P} = \frac{1}{0.0703} \approx 14$ people to run into one (so maybe that translates into having to question $13$ *before* you run into one)

The math behind this is a bit technical, but this is a well-known formula. E.g. You can expect to have to roll a die $6$ times before you get the first $3$, as the chance of getting a $3$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.  Sometimes you have to roll the dice fewer than 6 times, and sometimes more than 6 times to get the first $3$, but on average it turns out it takes $6$ rolls. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179670/john-keeps-rolling-a-standard-six-sided-dice-until-it-comes-up-as-a-6-what-is-t) is a question with some answers that try and make some sense as to why this is so.

Comment: @alisonmonroe You're welcome!  I added a link where you see some of the math that explains why it is $\frac{1}{P}$